# A question on an equivalent formulation of bounded unsigned measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure, uniform-convergence

The problem is:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to [0,+\infty]$. Show that the following two statements are equivalent.
>
> $(i)$ $f$ is a *bounded unsigned measurable function*.
>
> $(ii)$ $f$ is the *uniform limit* of a sequence of *bounded unsigned simple functions*.

I've done the $(ii) \to (i)$ part which was straightforward, but have confusion on the $(i) \to (ii)$ part. We're given that $f$ is a *bounded unsigned measurable function*. Since it is an unsigned measurable function, we can write it as
$$f=\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n$$
where for all $n$, $f_n$ is an *unsigned simple function*. I've taken care of the *bounded* part in the following way (*please see if there's any technical flaw here*):

For every $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $\exists~ N=N(\epsilon, x) \in \mathbb{N}$, which may depend on $x$, such that
$$\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert \leq \epsilon ~\forall~ n \geq N \cdots (\star)$$
We know that $f$ is bounded. So $\exists~ B \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq B ~\forall~ x \in \mathbb{R}^d$$
Coupling this with $(\star)$ and employing the *triangular inequality* it is easy to see that $f_n$ is bounded, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

> The only thing left is to show that the convergence is *uniform*. What can I do here? We need to get rid of the *dependence* of $N$ in $(\star)$ on the choice of $x$. My guess is that we can use the boundedness of the functions to show that $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} N(\epsilon, x)=N(\epsilon)$ is a finite quantity and we can use it in $(\star)$ to show uniform convergence. But how to do it in a rigorous way? Maybe this line of attack is trivial or maybe it is completely out-of-track, so apology in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a construction that shows this direction:

1. $f$ is bounded, wlog say its bounded by 1. For every natural $n$ break the interval $[0,1]$ into $2^n$ intervals of length $2^{-n}$.
2. Label $A_i$ the $f$-preimage of $[i2^{-n},(i+1)2^{-n}]$, $i=0,\dots 2^n$.
3. Now you define a simple function $\phi _n$ as $$\phi _n=\sum _{i=1} ^{2^n} 2^{-n}i\chi _{A_i}$$
4. The $\phi _n$ converge uniformly to $f$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate why this construction works? We see that $A_0 \subset A_1 \subset \ldots$ Suppose $x_0 \in A_0$. It seems to me that $\phi_n(x_0)=\sum_{i=1}^{2^n}i$, which diverges as $n \to \infty$, where as $f$ is bounded.

Comment: I missed a $2^{-n}$ in the construction. Think about a step function approximation to a smooth function.

Comment: Choose $x$ such that $f(x)=0$. Then $x \in A_i ~\forall~ i=0(1)2^n$. Hence $\phi_n(x)=2^{-n}\sum_{i=1}^{2^n}i=\frac{2^n+1}{2}$, which still diverges as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Fixed again. Sorry for being careless in my writing. Every set $A_i$ corresponds to the preimage of an interval of length $2^{-n}$. The sets are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: This was really helpful :) Thanks for the wonderful construction.

Comment: Just to be technically correct, in the definition of $A_i$, maybe we should use semi-open intervals $[i2^{-n},(i+1)2^{-n})$ for $i=0(1)2^n-2$ and $[1-2^{-n},1]$ for $i=2^n-1$ (just to make the $A_i$'s disjoint).